# Gaussian-Jordan Elimination question?

Tags: matrices

I have the linear system

$$
\begin{align*}
2x-y-z+v&=0 \\
x-2y-z+5u-v&=1 \\
2x-z+v&=1
\end{align*}$$

Very well. I form the matrix

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
2&-1&-1 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
1&-2&-1 & 5 & -1 &1 \\
2&0&-1 & 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

So I thought about exchanging the first row with the second one,and the first column with the last column. The first row is $a1$,the second $a$2 and the third $a3$. So what I do is find $a3-a2$ ,then multiply $a1$ by $-2$, then do $a2+a1$ , then $a3-a1$, this way I will have a $scaled$  $matrix$ and it will look like

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
-2&2&2 & -10 & -4 &-2 \\
0&-3&1 &-10 & -5 &-2 \\
0&0&0& 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

When I proceed with the Gaussian method, I don't know what to multiply or divide to get some of the numbers in the matrix zero. Help me ? Please.

Comment: this question needs editing!

Comment: Dont vote this down,I'm editing it please!

Comment: Can you please stop downvoting this? Please?

Comment: You can't interchange columns as you did...

Comment: :/....what do I do then?

Comment: Take a deep breath, relax, and don't worry about the downvotes. If you stick around (we hope you do), you'll accumulate reputation enough that downvotes won't matter. You've already learned a useful fact, that it's better to edit your question *before* you post it.

Comment: Look at the original augmented matrix.  You want to eliminate (that is "make $0$") the "$1$" in the second row, first column. How can this be done by using *row* operations? One way would be to take twice row two and subtract  row one; this gives you a new row two (notation $a_2\rightarrow 2a_2-a_1$). This gives $[0\ -3\ -1\ 10\ -3\ | 2]$ as the new row two. Now eliminate the "$2$" in row three, column one (by using row one).  Write down the new matrix obtained. There will be only one more elimination needed (eliminate the entry in the third row, second column using the new row two).

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

**Updated**

Variables arranged using $(x, y, z, u, v)$.

From your system, we have:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
2&-1&-1&0&1  &0 \\
1&-2&-1 &5&-1& 1 \\
2&0&-1 &0&1& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The row-reduced-echelon-form should be:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
1&0& 0 & -5 & 2 & -2\\
0&1&0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\
0&0&1 & -10&3&-5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Regards

Comment: The usual collation order for unknowns goes $x, y, z, u, v, w, \ldots$. That doesn't match alphabetical order, but tradition is tradition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks for that tidbit! Regards

Comment: Nice job!  I keep forgetting how to format the vertical bar in an augmented matrix (when I need to use it)!

Comment: @amWhy: To be honest, I use so many of these infrequently, I have to go to my cheat sheet to recall it! :-) Thanks for all the support!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've done everything right so far

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
-2&2&2 & -10 & -4 &-2 \\
0&-3&1 &-10 & -5 &-2 \\
0&0&0& 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now, let the first row be L1, the second L2, the third L3.

L1$\times$(-0.5) and then, L1-2L2.
You got
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
1&-1&-1 & 5 & 0&-1 \\
0&-3&1 &-10 & -5 &-2 \\
0&0&0& 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

next, you do L2$\times$(-1/3)-(5/3)L3. You got

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
1&-1&-1 & 5 & 0&-1 \\
0&1&-1/3 &10/3 & 0 &-2/3 \\
0&0&0& 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Finally, L1+L2, you have:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
1& 0& -4/3 & 25/3 & 0&-2 \\
0&1&-1/3 &10/3 & 0 &-1 \\
0&0&0& 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$